# Issue in count down days hours minutes from NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I am struggling with updating UILabel for count down for that I use following code

```
- (void)updateLabel {

    // convert date string to date then set to a label
    NSDateFormatter *dateStringParser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateStringParser setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSLog(@"date from update label %@", _selectedBirthdate);
    //OUTPUT  date from update label  07/23/2013

    NSDate *date = [dateStringParser dateFromString:_selectedBirthdate];

    NSLog(@"date from update label %@", date);

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceNow]; ///< Assuming this is in the future for now.

    NSString *stringVariable = [self stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];

    self.dayLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringVariable];
      self.hourLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringVariable];
      self.minutesLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringVariable];
       // i want to update this day hour minutes lable like this much of days hour and minutes remaining 

    NSLog(@"%@",stringVariable);

}
```

I use following method for counting days hours and minutes but I dont know whats the logic mind is not working here how to find days hours and minutes from interval

```
  - (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
        NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
        NSLog(@"%d",ti);
        //  NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;

         NSInteger days = (ti * 60);

        NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;

         NSLog(@"%d",minutes);



        NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
         NSLog(@"%d",hours);

        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i hours : %02i min", hours, minutes];
    }
```

Comment: please check my answer of this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505837/count-down-timer-iphone/13506213#13506213

Answer (score 1):

To count no. of days, months and years, apply below code.

```
double differenceSeconds;
double datediff;
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
long long tdate =[todayDate timeIntervalSince1970];
datediff = tdate - yourdate;

int days=(int)((double)datediff/(3600.0*24.00));

int diffDay=datediff-(days*3600*24);

int diffhours=(int)((double)diffDay/3600.00);
int diffMin=diffDay-(diffhours*3600);
int diffminutes=(int)(diffMin/60.0);
```