# iOS count down timer to a given date

Tags: ios

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505837/count-down-timer-iphone#) and while its very good. It does not seem to be working for me.

Here is my modification to the code:

```
-(void) updateCountdown
{
    
    NSString *dateString = @"2015-12-15 15:29:32";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    
    NSLog(@"DATE: %@ %@",now, dateFromString);
    
    NSDateComponents *componentMint = [calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    
    self.lblMinitSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentMint.minute)];
    
}
```

The time is being updated and everything is working fine except that it is disregarding the hour, minute and second marks that I have indicated.

That is:

```
    NSString *dateString = @"2015-12-15 15:13:32";
    NSString *dateString = @"2015-12-15";
```

No matter which of the two lines above I use, the remaining time is the same.

Furthermore, Id like to obtain Hours, Minutes and Seconds to the same time.

Say its 1pm and the time/date indicates 2:30pm same day.

I want the output of the hour to be 1.5 h
I want the output of minutes to be 90m
I want the output of seconds to be 5400s
and so on
NOT
1 hour, 30 min, 0 seconds

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:**

The main error here is that the countdown happens to a specific date and ignores the time.

I want the count down to happen from now to a specific TIME in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey there I have done this in my app, see if that helps you

```
- (void)updateRemainingTimeFromDateString:(NSString *)strDate
                                forLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

    NSString *strRemTime = @"";

    int timeInterval = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    if (timeInterval != 0) {
        int noOfDays = timeInterval / (24 * 60 * 60);
        timeInterval = timeInterval % (24 * 60 * 60);
        int noOfHours = timeInterval / (60 * 60);
        timeInterval = timeInterval % (60 * 60);
        int noOfMinutes = timeInterval / 60;
        int noOfSeconds = timeInterval % 60;

        if (noOfDays != 0)
            strRemTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dD", noOfDays];

        if (strRemTime.length != 0)
            strRemTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %02dH", strRemTime, noOfHours];
        else
            strRemTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02dH", noOfHours];

        strRemTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %02dM %02dS", strRemTime, noOfMinutes, noOfSeconds];
    }
    [label setText:strRemTime];
}
```

Sorry I haven't formatted it the way you want it but still that is not difficult to do, the date would be compared with the current date and label is passed along in this method as a parameter, so it can be updated with in method

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)callAfteroneSecond
{
    NSString *strDatehere = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Data_Dict objectForKey:@"d_expires"]];
    NSDateFormatter *heredateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [heredateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // set date formate with your dates

    NSDate *datehere = [heredateFormatter dateFromString: strDatehere];

    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [datehere timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];

    double hours = timeDifference / 3600;
    NSInteger remainder = ((NSInteger)timeDifference)% 3600;
    double minutes = remainder / 60;
    double seconds = remainder % 60;

    _lbl_buyTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fh, %.0fm, %.0fs",hours,minutes,seconds];

}
```

Comment: Your date does not have a minute, hour or second marker? `yyyy-MM-dd`! That was my biggest problem

Comment: I want the input date to be "2014-06-10 12:34". The way you have it formatted doesnt allow for a time. in my post `NSString *dateString = @"2015-12-15 15:13:32";`

Comment: and what you get result?

Comment: Wether I have the time in there or not, the result is the same

Comment: Can we just do it as if it was epoch time. Count down to some epoch time in the future display minutes of it?

Comment: in my code you get countdown time between today and entered date.

Comment: Right, I want countdown between now (date and time) to a given date and time. It needs to have a specific time!!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 3+ Version of @channi's Answer

```
private func setupTimer() {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(handleTimer(_:)),
                                     userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc private func handleTimer(_ sender: Timer) {
    
    var timeInterval = Double(Date().timeIntervalSince(self.dummyDate))
    var remainingTime = ""
    print("Timer: \(timeInterval)")
    if timeInterval != 0 {
        
        let noOfDays = abs(timeInterval / (24 * 60 * 60))
        timeInterval = timeInterval.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 24 * 60 * 60)
        let noOfHours = abs(timeInterval / (60 * 60))
        timeInterval = timeInterval.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60 * 60)
        let noOfMinutes = abs(timeInterval / 60)
        let noOfSeconds = abs(timeInterval.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
        
        print(" \(noOfDays), \(noOfHours), \(noOfMinutes), \(noOfSeconds)")
        
        if noOfDays != 0 {
            remainingTime = String(format: "%d D", Int(noOfDays))
        }
        
        if !remainingTime.isEmpty {
            remainingTime = String(format: "%@ %02d H", remainingTime, Int(noOfHours))
        } else {
            remainingTime = String(format: "%02d H", Int(noOfHours))
        }
        
        remainingTime = String(format: "%@ %02d M %02d S",
                               remainingTime,
                               Int(noOfMinutes),
                               Int(noOfSeconds))
        
        self.countDownLabel.text = remainingTime
    } else {
        sender.invalidate()
    }
}
```